# how to convert to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm fetching some string from backend in the following format, how to parse it into JSON.

```
"{messages:"[{message_type:S,message_text:Instance 20000001002700000279 of object type RentalObjectREFX has been changed.}{message_type:S,message_text:Email sent sucessfully}]"}"
```

Comment: use JSON.parse()

Comment: don't confuse your head too much, there are no such thing as JSON objects. JSON is text. Always. A codification for data. And i guess we wouldn't see these kind of questions if ppl read manuals, or just type a search on a web engine..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Like that

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{"messages":"[{message_type:S,message_text:Instance 20000001002700000279 of object type RentalObjectREFX has been changed.}{message_type:S,message_text:Email sent sucessfully}]"}');

console.log(json);
```